# How to create map for directory and sub-directory in JAVA

Tags: java, json, recursion, directory

I am new to java language I want to create a map with the File structure.

Problem: Given a main directory/folder, list all the files from it and if this directory have other nested sub-directories, list files from them also.

```
├── Folder1
│   ├── Folder2
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2
│   ├── Folder3
│   │   ├── file3
│   │   └── file4
├── Folder4
│   └── file5
├── Folder5
│   ├── Folder6
│   │   ├── file6
│   │   └── file7
│   └── Folder7
│       └── file8
```

I have a folder structure like shown above I want to create map for this structure as shown below.

```
  "CurrentDir": {
        "Folder1": {
            "Folder2": ["file1","file2"],
            "Folder3": ["file3","file4"]
        },
        "Folder4": ["file5"],
        "Folder5": {
            "Folder6": ["file6","file7"],
            "Folder7": ["file8"]
        }
    }

}
```

I did a code in java with print statements but unable to convert that in map. Following is my code. Please help me with this.

```
public class GFG 
{
     static void RecursivePrint(File[] arr, int level) 
     {
         // for-each loop for main directory files
         for (File f : arr) 
         {
             // tabs for internal levels
             for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
                 System.out.print("\t");
              
             if(f.isFile()) 
                 System.out.println(f.getName());
               
             else if(f.isDirectory()) 
             { 
                 System.out.println("[" + f.getName() + "]");
               
                 // recursion for sub-directories
                 RecursivePrint(f.listFiles(), level + 1);
             }
         }
    }
      
    // Driver Method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Provide full path for directory(change accordingly)  
        String maindirpath = "C:\\Users\\Gaurav Miglani\\Desktop\\Test";
                  
        // File object
        File maindir = new File(maindirpath);
           
        if(maindir.exists() && maindir.isDirectory())
        {
            // array for files and sub-directories 
            // of directory pointed by maindir
            File arr[] = maindir.listFiles();
              
            System.out.println("****************");
            System.out.println("Files from main directory : " + maindir);
            System.out.println("****************");
              
            // Calling recursive method
            RecursivePrint(arr, 0); 
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a proper JSON library such as Jackson or Gson. Then you could try to use maps for the JSON objects (keys would be properties) and lists for the arrays.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a json library (it's not natively supported) like `org.json`

Comment: I'll also reiterate the benefit of using a proper json library. Plus you will gain knowledge that's very useful today if you're taking this stuff seriously (which it appears you are)